# Probability of multiple events: continued

Tags: probability

I have 5 independant events.  How do I calculate the probability of event A occurring + 1 other?  How do I calculate the probability of event A occurring + 2 others?  What about the occurrence of A & B plus one other, but not the rest?  I have multiple variations of this I'm trying to figure out.

Event A:  15%
Event B:  30%
Event C:  15%
Event D:  10%
Event E:  10%

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/715597/probability-of-5-multiple-events

Answer (score 1):

The key here is to leverage independence. The first thing to note is that $A$ is independent of the event "at least one of $B,C,D,E$ occurs", so that
$$
P(A\cap\{\text{at least one of }B,C,D,E\})=P(A)\cdot P(\text{at least one of }B,C,D,E).
$$
So, how can you compute the probability that at least one of $B,C,D,E$ occurs? Well, for starters,
$$
P(\text{at least one of }B,C,D,E)=1-P(\bar{B}\cap\bar{C}\cap\bar{D}\cap\bar{E}),
$$
where $\bar{X}$ denotes the event that $X$ does not occur. But this probability is not bad to compute: the fact that $B,C,D,E$ are independent implies that $\bar{B},\bar{C},\bar{D},\bar{E}$ are independent as well, so that
$$
\begin{align*}
P(\bar{B}\cap\bar{C}\cap\bar{D}\cap\bar{E})&=P(\bar{B})\cdot P(\bar{C})\cdot P(\bar{D})\cdot P(\bar{E})\\
&=0.7\cdot0.85\cdot0.9\cdot0.9\\
&=0.48195.
\end{align*}
$$
Thus the probability that *at least one* of the events occurs is
$$
P(\text{at least one of }B,C,D,E)=1-0.48195=0.51805.
$$
I'll let you finish it up from here.

Comment: But you said $P(A)=0.15$ in the problem description...

Comment: P(A) alone I get 7.23%   P(A∩{at least one of B,C,D,E}) I'm getting 7.77% based on your formula.  Which seems counterintuitive to me.  am I doing something wrong?

Comment: by P(A) alone I mean P(A∩B ¯ ∩C ¯ ∩D ¯ ∩E ¯ )

Comment: Very helpful by the way... I forgot to mention that!

Comment: @ryan You got it right!  In the mean time, I realized I made it way too complicated (hadn't had my coffee yet), so I've revised with a more straight-forward solution.  Big thing to keep in mind: your calculations show that it is more likely that at least one of $B,C,D,E$ occurs than that none of them do; so, since $A$ is independent of them, it is more likely that $A$ and at least one of $B,C,D,E$ occur than that $A$ occurs and none of the rest do.